# Magento 2 : Images import through product import

Tags: magento-2.1, import

I am importing images through products import. But I am getting an error.

> "1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in a row(s): 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8".

My images folder is `pub/media/import`.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to import product images magento 2

```
$mainImage = $importProduct[9];

        if ($mainImage) {
            $image_directory = $mediaPath . DS . 'data' . DS . $mainImage;
            if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
                $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))//media gallery initialization
                    ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);//assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
            } 
            else {
                $image_directory = $mediaPath . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
                $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))//media gallery initialization
                    ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);
            }
        }

        // additional images
        if ($importProduct[29] != '') {
            $addImages = explode(",", trim($importProduct[29]));
            foreach ($addImages as $additional_image) {
                $image_directory = $mediaPath .DS.'data'.DS. trim($additional_image);
                if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
                } 
                else {
                    $image_directory = $mediaPath . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
                }
            }
            echo 'Additional images for product ' . $product->getName() . ' ' . $product->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
        }
```

Please click here for detailed explanation.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/import-product-images-magento-2-programmatically/